# Flutter FCM No Sound on Android 9.0

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

i made some application with flutter who can get notification from backend using firebase cloud messaging. I have a problem when application running on android 9.0. Sound not working even i using default sound. But when im running the app on android 7.0 sound working even i using custom sound. I already tried using :

```
<meta-data 
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" 
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

but still not working. Can everybody in here help me?

Answer (score 1):

Its current limitation of the library. For now, custom sound works only for Android 7 and below. Above Android 7 ,custom sound does not work and only default sound works. This is might because  Android after API>=26 implement something call notification channel. And currently we cannot set the channel Id from Firebase_messaging flutter plugin This are two different issues but some said the custom sound problem is because of the notification channel.
Notification channel problem :https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16022

Custom sound problem:
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26005

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24231942)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback bro. I have update my answer.

Comment: Even though it was answered a year ago, the problem still exists and I can surely say that default sound doesn't work as well on android 9

Answer (score -1):

I try FCM on android 9.0 for onResume and onLaunch not working even i have set default_notification_channel_id on manifest and send a payload that contains android_channel_id as same as I set in my manifest and application.kt that will create NotificationChannel with channel_id same with channel payload that I send..
how you received notification on android 9.0 (API 28)

Comment: I do not think this answers the question, please open a new question or upvote this one